# Is there an force attack button ? What are the workarounds?

Tags: diablo-iii

My problem is a bit specific: I am playing a monk with [thunderclap](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/fists-of-thunder), and I would like a way to attack mobs without having to click on every single one of them.

I have a **very** hard constraint: any the other spells in my build **cannot** be bound to the mouse left click button, so I am forced to have thunderclap as my left click.

Why is this a problem? Let's review how left and right mouse buttons work:

#### Left button

- Can be used to move.
- Attacks an enemy if you click on him.
- Attacks an enemy if you click on him, keep the button pressed and move the cursor elsewhere.
- **Does not** attack an enemy if you click to move, keep the button pressed and mouseover an enemy.
- **Does not** attack an enemy if you click an enemy, kill it, keep the button pressed and mouseover another enemy.

#### Right button

- Can be used to move.
- Attacks an enemy if you click on him.
- Attacks an enemy if you clock on him, keep the button pressed and move the cursor elsewhere.
- **Does** attack an enemy if you click to move, keep the button pressed and mouseover an enemy.
- **Does** attack an enemy if you click an enemy, kill it, keep the button pressed and mouseover another enemy.

The problem with the stand still button to force attack is that if I am a bit too far, I will just keep attacking nothing. With thunderclap, force attack using the stand still key does not make much sense, and it feels very uncomfortable. Thunderclap as left click is a pain.

So if I bind my thunderclap to the right button, it is perfect, I just smash enemies but having my right button always pressed, and my movements/attacks are optimized and feels comfortable. But in order to have thunderclap in my right click, I have to give up an other skill and put something useless as my left click.

Does a force attack button or mechanic exists? (when pressed, automatically attacks if you mouse over an enemy, and moves towards him if necessary). In a sense, right click = left click + force attack button pressed.

Do you see a workaround ?

Comment: One thing you have wrong is that if you're holding click and an enemy dies, and you immediately mouse over another enemy who was right next to the first enemy, you will continue to attack.

I should also point out that if you're using thunderclap, you'll teleport to your enemy every first strike in your combo even if you have shift held, so you might miss at most 2 attacks if you use shift.

Comment: @MrSmooth if you are too far from the enemy while holding shift, you will just keep attacking nothing. Also, if you are a bit too far and you don't have the teleport up, it would be faster to just move instead of doing 2 swings and then teleport.

Comment: @MrSmooth I've just tried: if you left click an enemy, keep the mouse pressed, and then mouse over another enemy: your will almost always move in between (even if it is very short), and then if you mouseover the next enemy you will move towards him. Just give it a try: slay enemies with thunderclap on left then right button. It's a no-brainer.

Comment: I found turning off sticky keys so I can spam holding shift whenever I need to make quick stops one of the easiest ways to work around this. Since only your first attack TPs you to your target you can hold shift to dash around targets close together release it get in range of the next mob and then hold it again and click him, wash rinse repeat. It's the only real solution I can think of other then saying change one skill on your build so you can use this as your right click. 

I did try it with right click and you are right it feels much nicer. I use dashing strike to move around combat though

Comment: Holding shift forces you to attack.  If you bind a key to move, you can use that key to move and shift+click to attack.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry, but I don't think there is a workaround aside from using a script to alter the game...which is strictly prohibited (thanks for that, Blizzard).

The options menu states that the Move/Primary Attack/Interact actions are all going to be bound to a single key, and unfortunately, that means you have to hone your clicking accuracy or try using a different skill.

I had the same problem when I first started running with my Witch Doctor. The Poison Dart skill was flat-out annoying to use because of the pinpoint accuracy required to hit enemies with the attack. However, if you keep at it, chances are you'll pick up on how to use the attack effectively; just as I did. Practice!

Answer (score 0):

There is a way. Go to Options/Gameplay and check "Elective Mode". Now you can bind any of your skills to any button in your action bar. Just press S, click the desired slot and use the arrows to find the skill yuo need.
Maybe it was not available in earlier patches but now they've added it.

Comment: That's...not anything to do with force attacking.

Answer (score 0):

Shift force you stay on the ground, and it force attacks if you are holding mouse 1. Just bind shift to another mouse button and when you want to attack, just click it.